# Is it possible to use a global variable when creating a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Appointment_Status` (
    `StatusID` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `AppointmentFulfilled` ENUM('fulfilled', 'noshow', 'cancelled')
);
```

Is it possible to define a global variable like this on the very top level:

```
SET GLOBAL AppointmentFulfilled = ENUM('fulfilled', 'noshow', 'cancelled');
```

And use it when creating a table? Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Appointment_Status` (
    `StatusID` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `AppointmentFulfilled` AppointmentFulfilled 
);
```

Comment: No. As an alternative create a table for the values and a foreign key to validate in your `Appointment_Status` table . An explanation of the driver for your question might elicit other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support User Defined Types (UDTs), however you can put a CHECK constraint onto your `Appointment_Status` table that will have the effect you are aiming for here. E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE `Appointment_Status` (
    `StatusID` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `AppointmentFulfilled` VARCHAR(9) CHECK (AppointmentFulfilled IN ('fulfilled','noshow','cancelled')) 
);
```

Full details at https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/creating-table-advance/constraint.php#cons3

Comment: why does this have the effect I was aiming? In the `CREATE TABLE` I still need to define the variable details?

Comment: @one-hand-octopus you still need to define the variable details somewhere - either in a UDT (can't use) or inserted into a table as suggested by P.Salmon.  A UDT would have to be included each time you use the table (probably why you can't use them), my approach does the same as having a UDT with those values, P.Salmon's approach allows you to easily extend the potential values over time.
Surely the effect you are aiming at is to limit the values that can be entered into that column? If that was not the intent then state the problem clearly.